# How can I count the number of CSV columns when the file has multiline data and no header

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

My CSV files have no headers and multi line entries like this:

```
11;"multi line
col12";13;foobar;foobar
21;22;23;24;25
```

And I'd like to count the number of columns. So 5 in this example. How do I do that?

**What I tried:**

`Import-CSV` doesn't work without the header parameter due to duplicate entries on the first line.

```
(Import-Csv .\bad.csv -Delimiter ";" | get-member -type NoteProperty).count
```

Adding a header parameter skews the count.

```
(Import-Csv .\bad.csv -Delimiter ";" -Header (1..99) | get-member -type NoteProperty).count
```

I had to abort reading the file manually via Get-Content because of all the parsing I would have to handle manually. Escaping characters and multi line entries...

My version of PowerShell is 3 and I have to port my script to version 2 later on.

Comment: How do you differenciate the linebreak in a value, from the CSV linebreak ?

Comment: CSV field names are supposed to be unique. I suggest you fix the cause (your input data) instead of dealing with the symptoms.

Comment: @Matt Multi line CSV are controversial but supported by Import-Csv and I can't avoid them. http://www.heikniemi.net/hardcoded/2010/01/powershell-basics-1-reading-and-parsing-csv/

Comment: @sodawillow The same way you deal with any embedded delimiter: double quotes.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't have control about what and how something is exported so I can't "fix" the cause. Excel can correctly import my sample so there must be a way to find the number of columns without providing a header.

Comment: Can't you open the file with Excel and count the columns in there, then ? : ) (with PS I mean)

Comment: I've done this before, but I didn't have multi line fields.  All I did was get the first line and split it.  I would try reading the first line and counting the number of double quotes.  If it's odd, then it's multi line and you need the next line.  Keep reading lines until you have an even total number of double quotes.  Then join those lines, and split on your delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Excel knows, let's ask him :

```
$path = "path\to\bad.csv"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($path)
$sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet

$columnIndex = 1
while($sheet.Cells.Item(1, $columnIndex).Text -ne "") {
    $columnIndex++
}

"There are $($columnIndex - 1) columns in CSV file $path"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
Get-Process excel | Stop-Process -Force
```

As pointed out by **Ansgar Wiechers** in comments, there is a much shorter solution :

```
$path = "path\to\bad.csv"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($path)
$sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet

$columnCount = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
"There are $columnCount columns in CSV file $path"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
Get-Process excel | Stop-Process -Force
```

(I know my way of killing Excel is dirty, but *iirc* it takes too much code to do so)

Comment: This would be a good way to address the issue if Excel is installed on the running system.

Comment: ... and any empty cell in dataset = `break`

Comment: `$sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count`. Beware, though, that Excel is rather picky about what it accepts as a CSV.

Comment: Of course it's much easier when you know how to use the Excel COM object properly ... : ) Thanks Ansgar.

Comment: Good idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to accept the caveat that this could miscount the number of columns if there are quoted delimiters in string this could be good enough for you.

```
$path = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$delimiter = ";"

$numberOfColumns = Get-Content $path | 
    ForEach-Object{($_.split($delimiter)).Count} | 
    Measure-Object -Maximum | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum

Import-Csv $path -Header (1..$numberOfColumns) -Delimiter $delimiter
```

Read in the file with `Get-Content` and isolate the maximum number of columns by 
splitting each line on its delimiter and then using that value to import the CSV. If the file is large you can read in the file once with `Get-Content` and then use `ConvertTo-CSV` once you know your column count.

---

If all lines contain a line break on them the above logic would fail. Still we could temporarily scrub the data by removing the correct line breaks in order to get the accurate count.

```cs
$delimiter = ";"
$fileData = (Get-Content $path | Out-String) 

$numberOfColumns = ((($fileData -replace "(`"[^;]+?)`r`n",'$1') -split "`r`n" | Select -First 1).split($delimiter)).Count

$fileData | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header (1..$numberOfColumns) -Delimiter $delimiter
```

What this will do is find lines that end where there is a double quote followed by data that does not contain the delimiter. We also match the newline that follows but drop that same new line in the replacement. If that is done we know that the first line is proper. Use that same line to split and count just like before.

Comment: If each line contains at least a value with a linebreak, does the algorithm get the count right ?.

Comment: @sodawillow Of course that would not work no. That possibility is not made clear from the sample data or the OP. However it should be easy to account for that possibility so I will update.

Comment: Your edit is what I had in mind at first, but stopped trying to figure out the code as soon as I read about Excel ^^. Looks good. I don't know if importing the file is needed, after all : ).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, but I came across a similar situation (did not have have rows of varying columns) today and found my own solution so I thought I would share for anyone else coming into this situation.  My solution was to use Get-Content for the first row of the CSV and -split on the delimiter (,) to create an array and then return the count of the array.  As mentioned in replies above, this will not account for delimiters existing within quotations.

```
((Get-Content $PathToCsv)[0] -split ",").count
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and went with AAgent suggestion.

```
$CommaCount = ((Get-Content $PathToCsv)[0] -split ",").count
$SemicolonCount = ((Get-Content $PathToCsv)[0] -split ";").count

if ($CommaCount -gt $SemicolonCount){
    $CMSlist = Import-Csv ($PathToCsv) –Delimiter “,”
}
else{
    $CMSlist = Import-Csv ($PathToCsv) –Delimiter “;”
```